Permission Revoke Issue in MS Graph API Token (OAuth 2.0 Authorization Code Flow)
Description:
I’m using OAuth 2.0 Authorization Code Flow with the Microsoft Graph API to authenticate users and access resources like emails, profile information, etc. Initially, everything works fine, but after a few days, I start receiving 401 Unauthorized or 403 Forbidden errors when trying to fetch a new access token using the refresh token.
Problem:
After some time (usually a few days), the application fails to retrieve an access token using the refresh token, and the following errors occur:

401 Unauthorized or 403 Forbidden

Context:
I am using the following scopes:

openid profile email Mail.Read Mail.Send offline_access (for obtaining
a refresh token)

The initial access token and refresh token are obtained successfully, and I am able to interact with Microsoft Graph API endpoints without any issues for the first few days.
However, after a few days, when I try to use the refresh token to get a new access token, it results in a 401 or 403 error, which indicates that the token is no longer valid, even though the refresh token is supposed to be long-lived.
Despite my app being verified and implementing a rate limiter, I’m still encountering this issue.

Could please share the entire error message and edit the question?

can you add the API endpoints and the body params that you used

after a few days, when I try to use the refresh token to get a new access token, it results in a 401 or 403 error may I know whether this error would occur if you try to get a new access token with refresh token when after 1 day or just passed several minutes? Refresh tokens have a longer lifetime than access tokens. The default lifetime for the refresh tokens is 24 hours for single page apps and 90 days for all other scenarios. But we don't know whether you changed the lifetime policy for refreshtoken

Look out for:
1.User or Admin Consent Revoked: If the user or an admin revokes consent to your app, then the refresh token will become invalid. In this case, the user will need to grant consent again.
2.Password Change or MFA Setup: If the user's password changed or if a sensitive security event occurred in the user's account (like MFA setup), then the refresh token will be invalidated.
3. Conditional Access: Check if there are any Conditional Access policies enforced in your Azure AD tenant that could be causing this issue ie. policy related to sign-in frequency enforced in this tenant.
